# NextJS 13 and TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

Next 13 use SSR by default and you need to specify when use client side rendering writing on the top:

```
'use client'
```

I'm using TypeScript and styled-component.

In this code:

```
import { LabelX } from "./../styled.form"
type LabelProps = {
    children: string;
    htmlFor: string;
}

export default function Label({ children, htmlFor }: LabelProps) {
    return (
        <LabelX htmlFor={htmlFor}>
            {children}
        </LabelX>
    )
}
```

I'm getting an error if I don't include 'use client'

Can anyone explain me why and what is causing that?

Comment: Some part of your component does not support SSR. [https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/client-components](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/client-components)

Comment: What's the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because in nextjs 13, every component is assumed as server component by default. so if your component has something that does not support server component, like `useEffect`, `useState` you will get error and have to explicitly tell nextjs that it's a client component

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/client-components